# dotCMS: photogallery - Error creating thumbnail

Tags: photo-gallery, dotcms

I try to launch a photogallery in dotCMS 2.1. But I can't see the thumbnails and photos. I tried two ways:

1) using a macro

```
#photoGallery('/img/gallery/clenove')
```

I don't see the thumbnails in this case. If i click on a photo, it occurs only if I am logged in as an Admin (Although i checked the user rights).

The tomcat log follows:

> [25/09/12 10:56:54:577 CEST] ERROR image.ThumbnailImage: Error creating thumbnail from servlet: Can't find contentlet: c829ebd1-4719-491d-b915-ea2c8bc1f476 lang:1 live:false
>
> com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.DotContentletStateException: Can't find contentlet: c829ebd1-4719-491d-b915-ea2c8bc1f476 lang:1 live:false
>           at com.dotmarketing.exception.DotRuntimeException.fillInStackTrace(DotRuntimeException.java:33)
>           at ..

2) via Content -> Image Gallery -> Add New Content
 this displays the message: "There currently no images in the folder." But in the administratiion, I can see them.

Comment: I am using dotCMS 2.5 and I am encoutering the same problem, I can add that if I make a gallery with small photos it works: for example I have a directory with ad hoc thumbnails and all works fine. I'm gonna investigate this more deeper, but have you solved this problem? If positive, then how?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have had no success there. I manually added the photos and pictures one by one. (FYI my version of dotCMS was 2.1.1 - community edition).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you published the images?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it more than once, to publish the images and they have been published all the time. I also tried to edit the acces rights to the files and folders (by granting all rights to anybody) but without success.